# Microsoft Exchange Out of Office reply interval

Tags: exchange-2010

I know that if a mailbox sends an Out of Office message to a particular address it will not send an OOO to that address again.

Does that behavior expire?

For example, it would be good if instead of only sending one OOO for the entire 3-week vacation, it sends it once per sender per day (or every couple of days). So if you send an email to someone and forget that they are out, you're reminded again when you send them another email a couple of days later.

I'm specifically interested in Exchange 2010 but I'll entertain answers from other version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior doesn't expire until the Out Of Office is disabled/turned off and then back on again, it will only send out a single reply to a user during that period.  My understanding is that this to help prevent mail loops from occurring.

If this is for you personally, you can use the Exchange Shell and script a scheduled task for yourself on the server that could enable/disable it once a week or whenever: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2667296

You probably don't want to mess with that for an end user, but it's available if need be.

That's the only way I'm aware of, short of creating a rule that replies every time to email coming in...even messing with the "except if received before/after" wouldn't really give you a rule that would fire well enough to only send them an "I'm not here" reply once a week.